# How to get the collection's length in ngRepeat when there is a filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

So I have a div like below. I want to show "help text" when the issues are null. Otherwise show issues.

```
<div ng-repeat="issue in issues|filter:{date:dateClicked}">
    <p ng-show="!issues">help text</p>
    <div ng-show="issues" ng-repeat="issue in issues"> 
      {{issue}} 
    </div>
</div>
```

I know I can check "issues", but I don't know what to do when there is a filter.

Comment: if there is jsfiddle link it would be lot easier to solve your problem

Comment: @BijayRai I edited the html, I just want to get the issues' length after filting, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="issue in issues|filter:{date:dateClicked}">
    <p ng-show="!issues">help text</p>
    <div ng-show="issues"> 
      {{issue}} 
    </div>
</div>
<span>lenght - {{(issues|filter:{date:dateClicked}).length}}</span>
```